# Symfony2: Persisting a parameter that indicates location, ideally without sessions/cookies

Tags: symfony

I'm using Symfony 2 to power a "kiosk" web application that runs on iPads we have in our building. There are three different kiosks located in different parts of the building. A core functionality of the kiosk is to provide the user directions to a specific office they are looking for, so each kiosk needs to know its location to give proper directions and floorplans.

I'm trying to figure out the best approach to "tell" the kiosk which location it is in. The iPad app loads a web page that I provide it. I've thought of:

1. Passing a query string var to the original URL loaded into the app, and use a request listener to persist it to session data (and set session lifetime > 1 year) or set it in a long lifetime cookie.
2. Using a route prefix that contains the location. So when loading the website into the kiosk app, I put in `http://myapp/north` or `http://myapp/south` for each location. Then each real route on the site is just added after the location part.

With #1 I have to worry about session cookie somehow being cleared locally or the session somehow being cleared server-side, resulting in the app "forgetting" its location.

I prefer #2, since the location is part of the URL and I don't need any sessions or cookies. But I'm not sure how to implement this in Symfony.

Comment: For item 2 just define your routes with a {location} parameter to all your routes.  However since this sounds like a strictly internal application then maybe you could just hard code the ip addresses of your kiosks.  I would not imagine them changing very often.